# String Manupilation Remove and Add String

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I am trying to remove part of `string` value from `var1` and then pasting it into another `var2` and then into `var2`. While doing so I update the values of the original variables. So if string length in `var1` exceeds max length of `10` it then carries out this manipulation.

The code shown below works fine however I am not sure if this is the best approach of removing part of string and assigning it to a `var`, updating the value in original variable etc

```
if (var1.Length > 10)
{
   var newVar2 = var1.Remove(0, 10); // Grab the string from var1 and assign
   var1 = var1.Remove(10); // Update value and remove the part of string
   var2 = newVar2; // Save the newly removed string into var2
   if (var2.Length > 10)
   {
      var newVar3 = var2.Remove(0, 10);
      var2 = var2.Remove(10);
      var3 = newVar3;
   }    
}
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: For starters you can just assign `var1.Remove(0, 10)` to `var2` as you're not using `var2` prior to that assignment of `newVar2`. The same can be said with `newVar3`.

Comment: What are you going to do with those parts afterwards? Why only going through to "var3"? Is not ever going to exceed 30 chars? ... Have you considered breaking it up into a `List<string>` or `string[]` to be more flexible?

Comment: @PerpetualJ thank you for the answer, it makes sense with your suggestion :)

Comment: @Fildor this is just an example I used for the suggestion. Yes it can, hence the usage of other `var3` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches for string manipulation, but for your case just slimming down your code a bit to remove unneccesary assignments and instantiation should be fine:

```
if (var1.Length > 10) {
    var2 = var1.Remove(0, 10);
    var1 = var1.Remove(10);
    if (var2.Length > 10) {
        var3 = var2.Remove(0, 10);
        var2 = var2.Remove(10);
    }
}
```

Another option is to store the string in a `List<string>` via a loop; this way you won't need a new `var` for every occasion that the length exceeds `10`:

```
private List<string> SlimStrings(string var1) {
    List<string> vars = new List<string>();
    string val = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < var1.Length; i++) {
        if (i % 10 == 0) {
            vars.Add(val);
            val = string.Empty;
        }

        val += var1[i];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

In this situation the final string in `vars` should be less than or equal to `10` in length. Everything prior should be equal to `10` in length. You then access each `var` via it's index (remembering that `C#` is a zero based language):

```
List<string> vars = SlimStrings("askljdngakjdsfngiewurnkajsdnicoebrlpvknas");
var var1 = vars[0];
var var2 = vars[1];
var var3 = vars[2];
```

Now granted, you'll either have to know the `Count` of vars in the list prior, or come up with a system for accessing such as a loop like the one that created it (or a `foreach` loop for simplicity) following the same principal:

```
private void UseVars(List<string> vars) {
    foreach (string s in vars)
        DoSomethingWith(s);

    // OR
    for (int i = 0; i < vars.Count; i++)
        DoSomethingWith(vars[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @PerpetualJ your suggestion helps alot :)

Comment: `val += var1[i];`  where have you declared `var1`?

Comment: I guess that's your original string `var1`.

Comment: @Kevin The declaration for `var1` was implied but I'll add it.

Comment: @Kevin what's the purpose of the code to begin with?  Are you trying to chunk the string into multiple strings all 10 chars in length? Are you just experimenting with the string functions?  Would be easier to give you a more complete answer if it was more clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces count when working with strings.  Unless you truly want spaces in your new values, you should use trim() to remove leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: I agree with you @Tamara

Comment: @Tamara, I wouldn't say just `Trim()`; perhaps `Replace(" ", string.Empty)` if they truly don't want spaces at all.

Comment: replace will also replace any spaces between characters as well - so you have to be careful with that.  IE:  Hello World becomes HelloWorld.

Comment: @TamaraPattinson I understand that; that's why I stated if they didn't want spaces *at all*.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know what your requirements are given your question.  Strings are immutable so you're creating new strings when you do string the string manipulation that you've shown.  In general you'd like to create as few as possible.  If you're requirements are to create multiple strings from a single string you have no choice, if you're building a single string use StringBuilder.  If you're simply truncating the string then just do it in one shot:

```
        var input = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        Console.WriteLine($"{input.Length}: {input}");

        var truncated = input.Remove(0, input.Length - 10);

        Console.WriteLine($"{truncated.Length}: {truncated}");
```

Comment: Fails if input.Length < 10

Comment: Was only intended to show doing the removal in one step.  It's unclear what he's trying to do in general by using the multiple steps to remove chunks of the string.